# Seers of the Throne details

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, mage-the-awakening

Which Mage: The Awakening sourcebook has the most thorough info on the Seers of the Throne (perhaps allowing players to play SotT members)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **Seers of the Throne** [sourcebook](http://paizo.com/store/games/roleplayingGames/m/mageTheAwakening/v5748btpy85o4) would be an excellent first choice. **Reign of the Exarchs** also has a strong focus on the group.

Comment: Omg, there's a complete dedicated sourcebook about them? What a shame that I've missed it completely! Thanks for pointing it out! (I'll wait a bit with accepting this answer even though I seriously doubt anyone could come up with anything better. :))